# Which Intel CPU should I buy - Core i7-5820K or i7-6700K or i7-4790K?

Tags: gaming, pc, processor

I am confused about which one of these processors to buy. I will pair it with two NVidia GeForce GTX 980 Ti (SLI). Also, I don't plan on too many upgrades and also I won't be overclocking 'too much'. The processors:

- [**Intel Core i7-4790K**](http://ark.intel.com/products/80807/Intel-Core-i7-4790K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_40-GHz)

  - **Devil's Canyon Haswell Refresh**
  - **4 Cores / 8 Threads**
  - **4.00 GHz**
- [**Intel Core i7-5820K**](http://ark.intel.com/products/82932/Intel-Core-i7-5820K-Processor-15M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)

  - **Haswell-E**
  - **6 Cores / 12 Threads**
  - **3.60 GHz**
- [**Intel Core i7-6700K**](http://ark.intel.com/products/88195/Intel-Core-i7-6700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz)

  - **Skylake-S**
  - **4 Cores / 8 Threads**
  - **4.00 GHz**

The 5820K and 6700K are the same price and also require DDR4 RAM and 99/170 series chipset motherboards, all of which are expensive. The 4700K and its supporting platform are comparatively cheaper. I am not willing to spend a lot of money. I will be mainly gaming and apart from that just surfing on the 
internet.

**Uses:**

- Playing games like GTA V, Assassin's Creed Unity, WWE 2K16 etc. with > 60fps at 1440p
- Using Blender Cycles. If you don't know, Cycles uses pretty much **100%** of all your resources. It takes hours to render a complex image with my current GTX 260.
- Not much except the above. Additional (not required but still) - Good Handbrake performance.

**Budget**:
Total Build < $3000 (including a 1440p display but excluding other peripherals like mouse, keyboards, speakers, etc.). My build:

- CPU - (That's the question)
- Motherboard - (Cheapest with good features and SLI Support, depending on CPU)
- GPU - ASUS GTX 980 Ti STRIX 6GB GDDR5
- Memory - 16 GB DDR3 or 8 GB DDR4 (This might also be a deciding factor.)
- Display - ASUS PG278Q 1440p 27" Monitor
- Case - Corsair SPEC-02 Red
- PSU - Corsair RM-850
- Storage - 1x128 GB SSD + 1x3TB HDD. (Again, cheapest with the most gigs)

Comment: You don't provide a lot to work with. "Gaming" - what kind of gaming? "Not willing to spend a lot of money" - What is your budget? For you, what will make one CPU useful and another not useful?

Comment: 'Extreme gaming' I will add another GTX 980 Ti as probably the only updgrade. Budget - N/A. Which one of the three is the best?

Comment: @FarhanAnam If you're unwilling to spend a lot, define what your maximum is. If it doesn't matter, remove it from the question. Additionally, "best" is subjective - best by what criteria? Please add some more detail to your question about the situation you're going to be using this in.

Comment: The more specific you are, the better. Gaming? Give use the games you want to play. Don't want to spend a lot? How much do you have for the whole system? 2k? 1k? $500? What country are you in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between 16gig (i'm assuming that's what you're going for in gaming) of DDR3 and DDR4 is of about 40bucks (in france) so I think you could go with the 6700k, since you're not into overcloking that much.
The 5820k would have been the better choice if you're gonna buy more memory (for editing stuff) than that (it has double the bandwidth). But for gaming that's waaaay more than you need. And the 6700k has native USB 3.1 support so a little more future proof.

And you can probably find good deals on the 6700k in those upgrade kits. And lastly the 4790k actually does better than the 5820k in gaming in a few tests so if the price difference matters go for that one.

Comment: Well that's pretty clear, it's all about the money now, either the cheaper 4970k and cheaper ram and cheaper mobo? or the expensive 6770k and all that goes with it.
http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/digitalfoundry-2015-intel-skylake-core-i7-6700k-review
there you have quite a bunch of benchmarks and real life tests to see where the 6770k is worth the money ;)

Comment: future proof? i said I was not going to upgrade a lot. future proof not in terms of upgrade path but in performance when the latest games come out?

Comment: future proof as in having usb3.1 when the 3.0 is starting to get common. The 3.1 (gen2) is 10times faster. it's the little stuff in 5years time that'll make you glad you chose this and not that. I'm not talking about upgradibility. But you'll get external hardrives and what not connected to your pc (basic stuff from everyday life) and having usb3.1 speed instead of 3.0 will make a difference. ;)

Comment: i think I'll go for the Skylake then.